# VHDL - Making a clock from another module's output signal

Tags: text, keyboard, project, vhdl, clock

I am modifying a simple keyboard interface I [found](http://www.xess.com/projects/ps2_ctrl.pdf) on the net to my use. The idea is whenever there is a new scancode, it will make the output named "Scan_Dav" go high, and then go low. So when I direct Scan_Dav to another module as a clock, that module's clock will have a rising edge whenever a new ScanCode is pressed. Is there any error in my way of thinking? Because I tried it and directed the scancode and scan_dav to the rest of my project -which writes letters side by side with the given scancodes and shows them on seven segment display- the displayed text had 2 of each character ( i.e. when I write FLY the text was like FFLLYY). If there is no errors, I will share my code and ask you why it is not working. Thanks :)

EDIT: This is where the shifting is done according to values of Scan_Dav

```
signal bytes : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
signal Scan_Dav_Sync: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="00";
signal Previous_Scan_Dav: std_logic:='0';
begin
    process (clk) begin --, Scan_Dav) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
             Scan_Dav_Sync(0) <= Scan_Dav;
             Scan_Dav_Sync(1) <= Scan_Dav_Sync(0);
             Previous_Scan_Dav <= Scan_Dav_Sync(1);
             if (Previous_Scan_Dav = '0') and (Scan_Dav_Sync(1) = '1') then
                 bytes <= bytes (bytes'high-8 downto 0) & Data_in;
             end if;
          end if;
    end process;
```

This is where Scan_Dav comes from, the code is taken from [here](http://www.xess.com/projects/ps2_ctrl.pdf):
(You may ignore the filtering part)

```
    Architecture Behavioral of KeyboardController is
    signal PS2_Datr : std_logic;
    subtype Filter_t is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal Filter : Filter_t;
    signal Fall_Clk : std_logic;
    signal Bit_Cnt : unsigned (3 downto 0);
    signal Scan_DAVi : std_logic;
    signal S_Reg : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    signal PS2_Clk_f : std_logic;
    Type State_t is (Idle, Shifting);
    signal State : State_t;
    signal Scan_Code : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal Flag : std_logic:='0';

    begin
        process (Clk,Reset)
        begin
            if Reset='1' then
                PS2_Datr <= '0';
                PS2_Clk_f <= '0';
                Filter <= (others=>'0');
                Fall_Clk <= '0';
            elsif rising_edge (Clk) then
                PS2_Datr <= PS2_Data and PS2_Data; -- also turns 'H' into '1'
                Fall_Clk <= '0';
                Filter <= (PS2_Clk and PS2_CLK) & Filter(Filter'high downto 1);
                if Filter = Filter_t'(others=>'1') then
                    PS2_Clk_f <= '1';
                elsif Filter = Filter_t'(others=>'0') then
                    PS2_Clk_f <= '0';
                        if PS2_Clk_f = '1' then
                            Fall_Clk <= '1';
                        end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

            -- This simple State Machine reads in the Serial Data
            -- coming from the PS/2 peripheral.
        process(Clk,Reset)
        begin
            if Reset='1' then
            State <= Idle;
            Bit_Cnt <= (others => '0');
            S_Reg <= (others => '0');
            Scan_Code <= (others => '0');
            Scan_Out <= (others => '0');
            Scan_Davi <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge (Clk) then

    --  if Scan_Davi = '1' then
    --      Scan_Davi <= '0';
    --  end if;

            case State is
                when Idle =>
                    Bit_Cnt <= (others => '0');
                    -- note that we dont need to clear the Shift Register
                    if Fall_Clk='1' and PS2_Datr='0' then -- Start bit
                        State <= Shifting;
                    end if;
                when Shifting =>
                if Bit_Cnt >= 9 then
                    if Fall_Clk='1' then -- Stop Bit
                        Scan_Code <= S_Reg(7 downto 0);

                        if (Flag = '1' and Scan_Code /= "11110000")  then 
                        --to ignore makecode
                            Scan_Out <= Scan_Code;
                            Flag <= '0';
                            Scan_Davi <= '1';
                        end if;

                        if (Flag = '0' and Scan_Code = "11110000") then
                        --to ignore F0
                            Flag <= '1';
                            Scan_Davi <= '0';
                        end if;

                        State <= Idle;
                    end if;
                elsif Fall_Clk='1' then
                    Bit_Cnt <= Bit_Cnt + 1;
                    S_Reg <= PS2_Datr & S_Reg (S_Reg'high downto 1); -- Shift right
                end if;
                when others => -- never reached
                    State <= Idle;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
        Scan_DAV <= Scan_DAVi;
end Behavioral;
```

UPDATE: The only problem that remains is the delayed display and shifting of the letter and the text. While writing VHDL, I get nothing after pressing V, then I get V when I press H and it goes like that. The last letter does not appear until another key is pressed.It seems to be an issue about Scan_Dav, yet I can not resolve what it is. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Driving a clock input from logic output is generally bad practice (and some FPGA fabrics will not allow it at all).  Clocks run best when sourced from dedicated clock logic inside the part, and good designs should minimize the number of clocks.  Ideally you'd have only one, but that's not always possible.

Instead of running a clock input from logic, consider running everything off of one clock and use "enables" to activate the logic only when needed.  In this case, you would detect the rising-edge transition of `scan_dav` inside of the downstream module and only react when that transition occurs.  The detection logic would run off of the same clock as the `scan_dav` module.

I don't think this explains why you're seeing double characters, you would need to post some code to analyze.  However, I would recommend that you re-tool to not drive clocks from logic.

Comment: Hello,
I changed my module, I am now using one clock, that is 25MHz, for all modules. I dont know where the problem is, shifting operation is done right, but since the amount of adding is incorrect that makes me think there are more than one rising edges of Scan_Dav. I will share some code in the above post.

Answer (score 1):

If I see it right you avoid the F0 when you release the Key but you do not filter the second scancode. 
It's always like this

Scancode   ---    press Key
F0         ---    relesase Key
Scancode

on some Keys (e.g ALT GR) you can get an E0 too.

It not complete description but the most importand thinks are shown. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode

This would lead to the descripted problem. FLY -> FFLLYY.

Comment: I have modified my keyboard code, and what you pointed out seems to be right I appreciate it. Now I filter the first scancode and I only use the scancode after F0. This time, however, when I write FLY, I get the letter on the display at the next key press, I get FL. I am modifying the code(Shifter is same, keyboard controller is changed) in the first post and am waiting for some help again.

Comment: I've found the error here, the value of Scan_Dav does net change on the first keystroke, but works fine afterwards.